# rxjs conditional nesting observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code which is working as intended:

```ts
const sourceObservable = ... // irrelevant
sourceObservable.subscribe(x => {
    doAnyway(x);
    if (x.Id) {             
        doSometing(x);
    } else {
        // id Not set, get default Id
        this.idService.getDefault().subscribe(id => {
            x.Id = id;                  
            doSometing(x);
        });
    }
});
```

According to [this article](https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/) nested subscribes are to avoid. Thats why i tried to refactor the above code, using pipes. I tried to realize the if-else operation with [this Method](https://blog.rangle.io/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/), where filtering is used to create an observable branch for each option. And in the end they should be merged to subscribe.

```ts
const obsShared = sourceObservable.pipe(
tap(x => {
    doAnyway(x);
}),
share());

const obsIdNotSet = obsShared.pipe(
    filter(x => !x.kennzahlId),
    merge(x => idService.getDefault().subscribe(id => {
            x.Id = id;
        // doSomething(x) will nomore be executed here
        })));

// even though the true-part is empty I seem to need this to mergeing both options
const obsIdSet = obsShared.pipe( 
    filter(x => !!x.Id),
    tap(() => {
        // doSomething(x) will nomore be executed here
    }));

obsIdSet.pipe(merge(obsIdNotSet)).subscribe(x => {  
    // in case obsIdNotSet this will run with x.Id not set because x.Id will be set later
    doSometing(x);
});
```

This code does compile and run without errors, only does it execute `doSomething(x)` before calling `idService.getDefault().....` and though it will be called without x.Id being set.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Checkout this entire article on conditional work in RxJS https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-patterns-conditionally-executing-work/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the following is the cleanest way to handle that (according to me) :

```
source.pipe(
  tap(val => doAnyway(val)),
  switchMap(val => val.id ? of(val.id) : this.idService.getDefault())
).subscribe(id => {
  this.id = id;
  doSomething(id);
});
```

You can see how short and clear this is, and it does the exact same thing your first code was doing.

Comment: could I also provide a mapping function to map the result of `this.idService.getDefault()` if the result wasn't an Id itself?

Comment: Sure, `this.idService.getDefault().pipe(map(...))` (you can use pipes within pipes, there's no issue with that)

Comment: you must truly be my captain :)
Added `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` but it doesn't seem to be found. Im using angular 6

Comment: @LuckyLikey if it works for you, consider leaving an upvote and/or closing your question as resolved !

Comment: @LuckyLikey sorry, didn't see your comment edit (no notification for edits), try `rxjs` if you're using the latest version, otherwise it should work

Comment: `import { of } from 'rxjs';` it was. I somehow thought it was located in `rxjs/operators`

Comment: Operators are pipeable ... well, operators :) It means everything that goes into a `pipe`. For creation, it all come from `rxjs`. be careful, some words are in both (`combineLatest` for instance), so be careful abotu your imports !

Comment: so you are saying, that everyting that's within `rxjs/operators` can be used within pipes. so depending the source from where you import e.g. `combineLatest` it can be used with pipes or not.

Comment: Exactly. And to explain the difference, `combineLatest` as static (non-pipeable) signature take at least 2 observables, while `combineLatest` as instance method can take only one (the second one being the "piped" first observable). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyt7ys) to see the difference in syntax !

Comment: Thanks alot. I feel like im not the only one who might use this information. Have a great day :)

Comment: Same, good luck with your project ! (And it's all coming from [the documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) if anyone wants the source !)